# What does LaTeX do with commands generated by natbib's \bibcite?

Tags: natbib

For definiteness, consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Miller,
    author    = "A. P. Miller and K. C. Rowley",
    title     = "Move over",
    year      = "2001",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Let us cite the book \cite{Miller}.

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

In the .aux file, there will be the command

`\bibcite{Miller}{{1}{2001}{{Miller and Rowley}}{{}}}`.

The effect of that command is to generate a command named `b@Miller`, which can be invoked via

`\@nameuse{b@Miller}`

to give

`{1}{2001}{{Miller and Rowley}}{{}}`.

But how does LaTeX actually use this command `b@Miller`? For example, while `natbib.sty` defines `\bibcite`, in which `b@Miller` gets defined, I'm having trouble finding any place in `natbib.sty` where the content of `b@Miller` would actually be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard LaTeX `\cite{foo}` accesses `\b@foo` just as `\label{foo}` accesses `\r@foo`.  `natbib` adds a few extra fields so you can cite the work in different ways but the basic code in `latex.ltx` is

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\cite{%
  \@ifnextchar [{\@tempswatrue\@citex@checkblank}{\@tempswafalse\@citex@checkblank[]}}
\def\@citex@checkblank[#1]#2{%
   \IfBlankTF {#2}%
     {\@citex[#1]{\space}}%
     {\@citex[#1]{#2}}%
}
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \let\@citea\@empty
  \@cite{\@for\@citeb:=#2\do
    {\@citea\def\@citea{,\penalty\@m\ }%
     \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb\@empty}%
     \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi
     \@ifundefined{b@\@citeb}{\hbox{\reset@font\bfseries ?}%
       \G@refundefinedtrue
       \@latex@warning
         {Citation `\@citeb' on page \thepage \space undefined}}%
       {\@cite@ofmt{\csname b@\@citeb\endcsname}}}}{#1}}
                     %%%%%%%^^^^^^^^^%%%%%%%%%%
```